# Querying GraphQL APIs with node

Tags: node.js, graphql

currently my code looks like this. The problem is, it is serving me HTML instead of JSON. Am I querying the wrong location? Should I be using a package more sensible for handling this type of data? I just don't understand. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

```
    var request = require('request');
    var options = {
      url: 'https://api.psychonautwiki.org/?query={  substances {    name    effects {      name    }  }}',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
      }
    }
    request(options,callback);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL apis generally get `query` and the rest of your options in as the request body, and mostly use the `POST` http method. It seems like this api reacts to your GET request with a GraphiQL user interface, that's why you are getting html as response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `Accept` header to tell the server what you're expecting back.

```
'Accept': 'application/json'
```